# createCompositeKey and getStateByPartialCompositeKey return [object object]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Please help me about the following code

```
async getAllDetails(ctx, userId) {
    const getAllDetailsAsBytes = await ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey(
        'userIdcarId',
        [userId]
    )

    return getAllDetailsAsBytes.toString()
}
```

This function return only some [object object].

Comment: the `getStateByPartialCompositeKey` returns an iterator object, so you need to "unpack" the iterator.  There are some examples in other posts here.

Comment: check out iterator example in Fabric samples for similar query method here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/fabcar/javascript/lib/fabcar.js#L108